# Pass crypted informations between 2 laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-5

I need to pass crypted informations between 2 laravel with different app key. But on the 2nd laravel, I can't read datas.

What I tried (not working, normal):

```
Crypt::encrypt($request['infos'])
```

An other test:

```
$crypt=new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter('base64:mnBCwiIMaW5QqwEixWp79bunoYt0MGHTIhdOpkDd9Oc=', 'AES-256-CBC')
$crypt=$crypt->encrypt($request['infos'])
```

and

```
$crypt=new \Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter('mnBCwiIMaW5QqwEixWp79bunoYt0MGHTIhdOpkDd9Oc=', 'AES-256-CBC')
$crypt=$crypt->encrypt($request['infos'])
```

Error: `The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths`.

I tried to override `$this->key` attribute on the `__construct` method of `Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter`

and last one, I tried to override the `$key` on `register` method of `Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider`

On my 2nd laravel I've the same error: `The MAC is invalid`

Comment: I tried with and without "base64:" but check my answer it explains why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is a problem with windows environment: https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv/issues/219
I tried the same code on MAMP and it's working